# Excel turns my floats into integers

Tags: microsoft-excel, openoffice

The following is part of the output of a code I have written. When I open it with excel part of the floats turn into integers while others remain.

Wrong: 
[image: example 1]

Correct:
[image: example 2]

When I sort them in ascending order the 'wrong' values end up on top, before zero.  Also, as an example, there is a 5044 value that is shown as 0,00504 in excel.

*If I open it with word-pad though, all the values appear correctly, that's how I knew that it is not a programming error.*

What I have tried:

- unchecked automatically insert a decimal point,
- unchecked data range formats and formulas, and
- use system delimiters.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:
OpenOffice and Excel:

```
CHEMBL3652402   C[C@@H]1C[C@@H](CS(=O)(=O)N2CC[C@H](CO)C2)CC[C@@H]1N(C)c3ncnc4[nH]ccc34 CHEMBL2148  IC50    =   31  nan

CHEMBL3666730   CCCC(=O)Nc1ccccc1c2nc(Nc3ccc4[nH]ncc4c3)c5ccccc5n2  CHEMBL2973  IC50    >   55  276208
```

Wordpad:

```
CHEMBL3652402   C[C@@H]1C[C@@H](CS(=O)(=O)N2CC[C@H](CO)C2)CC[C@@H]1N(C)c3ncnc4[nH]ccc34 CHEMBL2148  IC50    =   0.031   nan

CHEMBL3666730   CCCC(=O)Nc1ccccc1c2nc(Nc3ccc4[nH]ncc4c3)c5ccccc5n2  CHEMBL2973  IC50    >   0.055   276208
```

Comment: Can you show us the same four lines in both Excel and Open Office? it will probably make it easier to see the difference between the two

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1506814/edit) instead of adding information in comments. Show us the correct and incorrect output for the *same* values

Comment: Apologies! It is now edited!

Comment: It would be better to post a small example file.

Comment: just comparing `0,00504` & `0.055` one has a comma, the other a period. Excel doesn't like using both for decimals. Which it prefers is dependant on your Language settings.

Comment: It could still be a programming error.  VBA is US-Centric in many respects, so if you are entering numeric values in VBA, using other than the `dot` for the decimal separator (and/or the `comma` for the thousands separatory) you may get unexpected results.

Comment: Try : open the data in notepad. Then select > copy > paste special in excel : space delimited.